# Bioshock has no sound in Windows 7

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, bioshock

I just bought a new PC with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. Everything is peachy except Bioshock: it has no sound after the game starts.

I've searched on Google but can't find a definitive answer; or else the definitive answer doesn't work.

I tried changing the configuration file to use a different sound output system.

I tried using compatibility mode.

Nothing seems to work. The game worked well for me on Vista.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I had the same problems. After spending several days of fruitless efforts, I finally simply reinstalled Bioshock (I have it via steam) and the sound finally worked.

Comment: @Juan http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1046/shooting-trouble-and-supporting-tech-yet-another-tagging-qualm

Comment: oh @badp; re-reading that -- done, I don't think it's a resolved issue, re-tag again if you like. Leave bioshock and sound though, I think they're useful.

Comment: What is your sound chip/card?

Comment: @Bora: It's a Realtek High Definition Audio ALC889 built into the Asus P6X58D-E motherboard.

Comment: Check this question out. I had the same exact issue (and created a reply to that question) http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/bioshock-on-steam-hangs-on-startup/9947#9947

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try enabling the so-called "Stereo mixing":

(from http://forums.2kgames.com/forums/showpost.php?s=2ab258ea92a1bfbe6c783657b3633730&p=255517&postcount=1)

> To do this, browse to Start > Control
>   Panel > Sound (in classic view). Once
>   done switch to the Recording tab which
>   will show the currently active inputs
>   on your system (e.g. Line in,
>   Microphone). Right click in the clear
>   space below these devices and select
>   the option for Show disabled devices.
>
> This should show an additional device
>   called Stereo Mixing, right click on
>   this device and select Enable.

Comment: I tried that, no luck.

Comment: Okay, let's try to narrow it down: Try running the game with the -dx9 command-line parameter and see if you get sound.

Comment: I recently re-installed the game on the same PC because I had to re-install Windows. THIS time I went straight to this approach before trying anything else. I installed the manufacturer's driver for the sound card (not the MS driver) and "stereo mixing" became available. I turned it on, and the problems were solved.

Comment: This worked for me - also had to set Compatibility Mode to `Windows Vista (Service Pack 2)` to get the video working right.

Answer (score 5):

I have been correctly been able to run Bioshock on windows 7 platform. I too had the same problem when I had installed it. No sound. Well I tried the following steps in that order and it worked for me:

Step 1. Just run the Direct X installer that came along with the DVD. I know, we all probably have a later version already installed but for some games this step actually does work. Don't ask me why. I don't know.

Step 2. Update to patch 1.1.

Step 3. Use a no-dvd crack. Since I have a laptop I usually prefer not to use the dvd drive to much unless there is no other option. Well the game ran with this so I didn't make any further changes.

Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter.  But I tried that too and it didn't work.  And installing a down-level version of DirectX seems a bit dodgey to me.

Comment: -1 for suggesting a no-dvd crack, where nowadays almost all of them contain malware.

Comment: There are lots of websites that contain malware. Just saying that you could even get malware in a lot of ways. Doesn't mean that you stop surfing completely, right? Instead of downvoting the answer itself I feel a more appropriate response might have been to voice your concern. I could have provided you with the link where I got a malware-free version.

Comment: Regarding step 1: this can sometimes fix issues because there were (and maybe still are) many different builds of DirectX 9 released; so having one particular build installed you may be missing components from another build that X game requires. Also, DX10/10.1/11 do not automatically include all components of DX9[x]

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by plugging in an extension cable into the front mic port on my case.  My soundcard detected that the mic was present.  After that the sound works.  I have no friggin' idea why this might affect anything.  I would still like someone to post a better solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Plugging in a microphone into the front port has worked for me as well. Windows 7 64 bit system. Had no sound before plugging in the microphone, but now it works with microphone plugged in. Try it!

Answer (score 1):

I had my HDMI plugged into my TV, and I guess the two audio outputs started competing. You need to right click audio manager, and then go click on audio devices. Once there you should make sure only one is enabled. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an alternative that worked for me as the other answers don't quite work that good (for me):

- [Enabling Stereo Mixing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/9402/4797) makes sound from my other programs and games sound weird (unclear and has echo).
- [I'd rather not plug in a mic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7950/4797) just for BioShock.

What worked for me was: in *BioShock.exe*'s Properties > Compatibility tab, is to set it to 'Windows XP' compatibility mode. I also set it to run as an administrator but I'm not sure if it helps (I've had it enabled from the start):

[image]

Notes:

- Like OP, I am also using Windows 7, 64-bit.
- Setting it to 'Windows Vista' compatibility mode doesn't work for me.