# Stuck on entry to Rapture

Tags: bioshock

So I see the first view of Rapture while in the bathysphere. As it stops, I can see some guy standing outside the window.. and then nothing.

I can look around with the mouse but can't move, interact or do anything else.

This is version 1, and the 1.1 patch doesn't fix the issue either. There's no sound as well after the air crash opening movie.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: What platform are you playing on? You didn't get the scripted event with the enemies attacking the bathosphere? Or the instructions on the radio? I assume you don't get to the shiny gold lever inside the bathosphere to let yourself out?

Comment: The PC version. I didn't get any scripted event, I can see out the window and look around but can't move at all. Sound doesn't work either. (updating question to add these).

Comment: "*the 1.1 patch doesn't work.*" You might want to ask another question on how to get that one installed in Windows 8 (which from your [answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/105935/4797), is the OS that you are using). The [1.1 patch fixes a lot of issues in the game](http://www.bioshockgame.com/support/), aside from adding useful gene tonics and plasmids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, apparently fixing the sound fixes everything else.

Open the 'Sounds' applet in control panel, go to the tab for recording devices, right click, and choose 'show disabled devices'. From here, select and enable the recording mixer, and then the sound works fine. This is a solution for Windows 7, and it also works for Windows 8 (which I'm using).

After the sound started working, the scripted events also work, and now I'm able to proceed further.

Comment: In 64-bit Windows 7, what I did to fix the no sound issue was to [run *BioShock.exe* in Windows XP compatibility mode. Enabling Stereo Mixing makes sound from my other games and programs sound weird (unclear and has echo).](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/103087/4797) Could you try and comment back if this method also works in Windows 8?

Comment: Well, after the stereo mixing I just continued playing the game at 1.0, and now I've finished and uninstalled it.